# Pulling Instagram images to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ipad, instagram

I'm developing and iOS app for iPad where you can personalize Tea Cups importing photos from the roll. I'd love to add Instagram, so the user could add his Instagram's photos. Is there any SDK or Plugin for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instagram has an API. You can get user photos using this API with simple HTTP requests. Check out [this page](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/).

Comment: Yes I know it, but then you have to work in some code to transform this JSON to native images. I mean some library with this code already made.

Comment: There is no such library that I know of. However it's quite easy to access Instagram API using [AFNetworking](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: @CagdasAltinkaya Do you know of a solution that involves photo selection via the actual Instagram app, with a callback to your proprietary app?

Answer (score 7):

You should check out this wonderful helper library which will save you precious hours working with the Instagram API. http://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

Comment: it seems really nice! but i don't need it now... i'll use it if i need some Instagram stuff someday :)